# trigger is firing only once for duplicate cron expressions

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz

When I try to schedule two different job with the same cron expression(0 * * * * ?) which is every minute, only one trigger is being fired. I almost tried everything but nothing worked. I also passed the parameter `spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount=10` but it didn't worked. At least one trigger is firing in a minute and sometimes two, but never two triggers fired in a minute continuously. Am I doing somethig wrong?

edit: I checked on db that Next_Fire_Time is being updated but not being triggered even not misfired or vetoed as I can see from my Trigger Listener.

```
public class GlobalTriggerListener implements TriggerListener {

    private static final String TRIGGER_LISTENER_NAME = "GlobalTriggerListener";

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return TRIGGER_LISTENER_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void triggerFired(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context) {
        String triggerName = context.getJobDetail().getKey().toString();
        System.out.println("triggerFired");
        System.out.println("trigger : " + triggerName + " is fired");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean vetoJobExecution(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context) {
        boolean veto = false;
        System.out.println("Veto Job Excecution trigger: " + veto);
        return veto;
    }

    @Override
    public void triggerMisfired(Trigger trigger) {
        System.out.println(getName() + " trigger: " + trigger.getKey() + " misfired at " + trigger.getStartTime());
    }

    @Override
    public void triggerComplete(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context, Trigger.CompletedExecutionInstruction triggerInstructionCode) {
        System.out.println(getName() + " trigger: " + trigger.getKey() + " completed at " + trigger.getStartTime());
    }
}





  private JobDetail buildJobDetail(ScheduledProcess sProcess) {
        JobDataMap jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();

        jobDataMap.put(JOB_DATA_KEY, sProcess.getSpid());

        return JobBuilder.newJob(ProcessStarterJob.class)
                .withIdentity(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "scheduled-processes")
                .withDescription("Start Process Job")
                .usingJobData(jobDataMap)
                .storeDurably()
                .build();
    }

    private Trigger buildJobTrigger(JobDetail jobDetail, ScheduledProcess sProcess) throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date startDate = formatter.parse(sProcess.getStartDate());
        Date endDate = formatter.parse(sProcess.getEndDate());

        return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity(jobDetail.getKey().getName(), "scheduled-processes-triggers")
                .withDescription("Start Process Trigger")
                .startAt(startDate)
                .endAt(endDate)
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(sProcess.getQuartzDef()).withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
                .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny but true. I think this the third time I am the victim of Eclipse. Although I couldn't see any instance running on eclipse there was always a stale running instance of my quartz app which I saw it on Task Manager by chance. However I even debugged the quartz source code :)

So if you face with the same problem I have, first of all be sure that there is no running any other instance of your app anywhere, this can also be another quartz app that may be using your quartz db. When I start to be suspicious about if there is any other running instance was the moment I saw that Trigger NEXT_FIRE_TIME was being updated as it has to be but I wasn't seeing any fire on my Trigger Listener.

Hope these help you to identify you problems.